# Como remover um item específico de uma lista duplamente encadeada?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Dado a classe No, sendo:

```
public class No<T> {

T elemento;
No<T> proximo;
No<T> anterior;

public No(T elemento, No<T> anterior, No<T> proximo) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
    this.proximo = proximo;
    this.anterior = anterior;
}

public No(T elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
    proximo = null;
    anterior = null;
}
```

}

Devo criar um método `boolean remover(T item)`, o qual tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
public boolean remover(T item) {

    if (primeiro.elemento.equals(item)) {
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        primeiro.anterior = null;
        return true;
    }

    No<T> n = primeiro;
    T aux1 = null;
    T aux2 = null;

    while (n.proximo != null) {
        if (item.equals(n.proximo.elemento)) {
            aux1 = n.proximo.elemento;
            n.proximo = n.proximo.proximo;
            break;
        }

        n = n.proximo;
    }

    n = n.proximo;

    while (n.anterior != null) {
        if (item.equals(n.anterior.elemento)) {
            aux2 = n.anterior.elemento;
            n.anterior = n.anterior.anterior;
            break;
        }

        n = n.anterior;
    }

    if (aux1 == aux2) {
        tamanho--;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Desse modo, eu consegui remover quase todos os itens, menos o último antes do `null`, quando o programa dá erro.

Existe algo a se fazer pra consertar isso ou até mesmo uma construção melhor para esse método?

Comment: O programa também dá `NullPointerException` se você tenta remover um item de uma lista vazia, correto?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Comment: Caso geral para remover um item de uma lista duplamente encadeada: Encontre o nodo a ser excluído e faça o `proximo` do anterior se tornar o `anterior` do próximo. Há dois casos especiais, que são a remoção no início ou no fim da lista. Para remover do início, basta tornar `null`o `anterior` do segundo elemento. Para excluir do fim, basta tornar `null`o `proximo` do penúltimo. Se a lista estiver vazia, o método `remover` pode ser retornado logo no começo.

Comment: Não tenho acesso ao Java no momento, então não posso criar nenhum código para lhe ajudar, nem rodar o seu código. Por isso me limitei a explicar apenas em texto.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas se você puder me mostrar depois, quando estiver disponível, eu ficaria agradecido. Fica difícil para eu visualizar assim.

Comment: Ok, se ninguém tiver respondido até lá, eu te ajudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois problemas código:

```
if (primeiro.elemento.equals(item)) {
    primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
    primeiro.anterior = null; //<-- esta linha (1)
    return true;
}
...
while (n.proximo != null) {
    if (item.equals(n.proximo.elemento)) {
        aux1 = n.proximo.elemento;
        n.proximo = n.proximo.proximo;
        break;
    }

    n = n.proximo;
}

n = n.proximo; //<-- e esta linha (2)

while (n.anterior != null) {
    if (item.equals(n.anterior.elemento)) {
        aux2 = n.anterior.elemento;
        n.anterior = n.anterior.anterior;
        break;
    }

    n = n.anterior;
}
...
```

1. `primeiro.anterior = null;` Se o proximo acabou de avançar com `primeiro = primeiro.proximo;` pode ficar num `null` o que irá dar `NullPointerException` quando fizer `primeiro.anterior`.

   Pode resolver este problema facilmente com um teste:

   ```
   if (primeiro.elemento.equals(item)) {
       primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
       if (primeiro != null){
           primeiro.anterior = null;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. `n = n.proximo;` Se o `while` avançou até ao ultimo (aquele em que o `proximo` é `null`) então avançar para o próximo vai fazer com que `n` fique a `null`, que irá dar `NullPointerException` na comparação do `while` que vem logo a seguir:

   ```
   while (n.anterior != null) {
   ```

   Esta instrução está mesmo a mais e basta apenas remove-la.

[Veja o seu código a funcionar no Ideone com estas duas alterações](https://ideone.com/rVAJCV)

---

Eu pessoalmente transformaria a remoção em algo mais simples:

```
public boolean remover(T item) {    
    if (primeiro == null) return false; //se está vazia não faz nada

    if (primeiro.elemento.equals(item)) {
        primeiro = primeiro.proximo;
        if (primeiro != null){
            primeiro.anterior = null;
        }
        return true;
    }

    No<T> n = primeiro;     
    while (n != null && !n.elemento.equals(item)){ //achar o elemento a remover
        n = n.proximo;      
    }

    if (n == null) return false; //se não achou sai com false

    n.anterior.proximo = n.proximo; //ajusta o proximo do anterior
    if (n.proximo != null){ //ajusta o anterior do proximo se existir
        n.proximo.anterior = n.anterior;
    }
    tamanho--;
    return true;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/etRU7O)

Note que contemplei adicionalmente o caso da lista já estar vazia no primeiro `if`, para não dar erro se tentar remover elementos quando já não tem nenhum. Uma das ideias por detrás das listas duplamente ligadas é que é fácil saber o elemento anterior e próximo, logo podemos diretamente navegar até ao elemento a remover e fazer os ajustes somente a partir desse.